# Word Automation Multiple Paste Problem

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

Is there a better way to paste HTML fragments into a Word document than via the clipboard from C#?

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

I'm using some code that puts HTML into the clipboard:

```
HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(changedText);
```

I have a selection in word (from a formfield) and I do:

```
 word.Selection.Paste();
```

But sometimes it just throws a COM exception.  If I add

```
  Thread.Sleep(100);
```

I can get it to work, but that's not ideal.

The Insert methods look like a better option but there is no Insert from HTML.

So what's the best way to insert lots of HTML fragments into Word quickly using the automation interfaces?

**Edit**

Some good advice in the responses but the issue turned out to be a simple `<br>` tag causing word to fail on paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For interop, instead of `Selection.Paste` you'll want to use [`Selection.PasteSpecial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.pastespecial%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with a [`WdPasteDataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdpastedatatype.aspx) of `wdPasteHTML`.

If you're using the new formats of Word (i.e. 2007/2010), you could give up interop all together and just go with WordprocessingML (using the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) or just free-hand it with Linq and System.IO.Packaging). Or you could just it in conjunction with Interop if that was a need.

If you're using Open XML, you could just use `altChunk` to import HTML. Here's an example (which includes an example for HTML) at [How to Use altChunk for Document Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx). And another (fresh off the presses - it was released today): [Importing HTML that contains Numbering using altChunk](http://ericwhite.com/blog/2011/03/27/importing-html-that-contains-numbering-using-altchunk/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it turned out that the issue was far simpler: trying to paste <br> into word via the clipboard using HTML fails.  Gave you a +1 anyway.

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried what you sait but wdPasteHTML gives error "Command Failed"?

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Otaku's comments, though, generally speaking, i've found it best to use the various RANGE.* functions for pasting in data than the Selection object, or pasting through the clipboard. the main reason is, if you paste through the clipboard, you scramble whatever was on the clipboard (which might not be what the user wants to happen).

the Selection object applies across all open word documents, which can get you in trouble in some cases. Unfortunately there are a few things that you just about can't do any other way.

And, there are some things (Like altering text at the current cursor position) that you MUST use the selection object for.

Comment: +1 agreed. Generally, `Range` is better than `Selection`, and even more appropriate in an interop environment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it turned out that the issue was far simpler: trying to paste <br> into word via the clipboard using HTML fails.  Gave you a +1 anyway.

Comment: I can't see a function in the Range object which allows HTML to be inserted, do you know if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to DarinH comments. Also something to note is that you can paste on any place in the document using Range without having to change the selection of the document (the cursor in the document).

Sometimes PasteAndFormat throws an Exception on freshly created Documents, check my reply here if that happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65796482/15001063